# Remove quotes in result of XSLT 3.0 xml-to-json conversion

Tags: json, xml, xslt-3.0

I'm new to the XSLT..

I'm doing xml to json conversion in that I'm using map function to display in the key and value format.

Here is my code

```
<map>
<string key="isEmpty">
<xsl:text>true</xsl:text>
</string>
</map>
```

its giving

```
{
"isEmpty":"true"
}
```

I want display

```
{
"isEmpty":true
}
```

I want to know how to remove/print only boolean value without quote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `<boolean key="IsEmpty">true</boolean>`, https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3Mvnt3s.